# erasing EditText and EditView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

This is linked to a previous post:
My layout is like this:

INPUT TEXT (EditText)

BUTTON

OUTPUT TEXT (TextView)

Task:
When the user enters an input and upon button click the output text appears.
I have to make sure I make the input and output disappear some 10 seconds after the button click(and after the output text appears).

Now, I cannot add a "TextWatcher" on TextView.
Initially I tried to use Handler on inputText which can have a TextWatcher. But somehow the Handler keeps running all the time in the background and I cannot "cancel" it.

So I switched to using timers. I used a method in the button onCick() method:

```
onClick(){
...
    eraseText();
....
}

public void eraseText(){

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
               inputText.setText("");
               outputText.setText("");
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000,10000);
}
```

And after 10 seconds I would like to call timer.cancel() ( but don't know where!!)
As you can see the problem is that I get an error complaining that only UI threads can change views. How can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I would start a simple `AsyncTask` with `Thread.sleep(10000)` in `doInBackground` - and then in your `onPostExecute` hide the output text.

Comment: use handler to update with the timer task, also when the button is click again , cancel and reset it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Handler class. You can easily post delayed code and cancel it. It will run in correct Thread. Also, you can add TextWatcher or OnFocusChangeListener to detect and cancel text erasing when a user starts editing text again.

```
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handler = new Handler();
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    final Runnable eraseText = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText("");
            editText.setText("");
        }
    };

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(eraseText);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(eraseText);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
            handler.removeCallbacks(eraseText);
            handler.postDelayed(eraseText, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Zielony, isn't handler.removeCallbacks(eraseText) the parameter a runnable and not a view element?

Comment: Yes, it's a runnable. You can ask the handler to remove all tasks based on the selected runnable to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

use **CountDownTimer**

Main UI changes can be done using CountDownTimer

```
    CountDownTimer cdt;
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(1000,10000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // you can make UI changes here after 10 seconds
           inputText.setText("");
           outputText.setText("");

        }
    };
```

Use these methods to start and cancel

```
    cdt.start();
    cdt.cancel();
```

Comment: wow this is something I have not come across so far... Let me try!

Answer (score 0):

prefer the `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable run, long delay`) method, it will run on UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

First, keep a reference to your `Timer` object (As a field in your class) so you can cancel it later.

Second, use the [`post`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method of your views to execute code on the UI thread.